# Create JSON listing all Jenkins specific environment variables within Groovy Script

Tags: json, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying (in a Groovy script executed via pipeline) to get all Jenkins environment variable values output in a json format.

So, for example:

```
{
   "branchName":"test/branchA",
   "changeID":null
}
```

Ultimately I would like to have this json written to a file in the workspace of the running job.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple stage using declarative pipeline can achieve this easily.

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
        stage('Write-Jenkins-Env-To-File') {
            steps {
              sh """
                jq -n env >> jenkinsEnvironmentFile
                cat jenkinsEnvironmentFile
              """
            }
        } 
    }     
}
```

Just ensure, that you've the `jq` linux utility installed in your jenkins agent.